# Запуск команды в подчиненном ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В приложении имеется главное окно и множество userControl. На главном окне расположены все кнопки управления (такие как: добавление данных, редактирование и другие). В UserControl расположены непосредственно данные. Как мне привязать исполнение команды в UserControl к кнопке на главном окне?

Сейчас использую схему, при которой обработка команд выполняется на главной ViewModel, из которой вызывается функция из подчиненной ViewModel.

```
_addNewItemCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItem);
public ICommand AddNewItem => _addNewItemCommand;

void AddItem()
{
 _currentVM.AddItem();
}
```

Соответственно в XAML разметке привязываю к кнопке эту команду:

```
<Button Content = "Добавить" Command = "{Binding AddNewItemCommand}"/>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Расскажите побольше о ваших VM. Какая между ними иерархия? Главная VM имеет ссылки на дочерние? Пробовали вариант типа `Command="{Binding ChildVM.AddCommand}"`, где `ChildVM` — свойство в главной VM, которое содержит ссылку на дочернюю VM, а `AddCommand` — команда, лежащая в этой дочерней VM?

Comment: Этих ChildVM не одна, и они меняются в зависимости от задачи, потребности пользователя и других условий. В главной VM ссылка на текущую ChildVM есть.
Спасибо за предложенный вариант. Пока есть ограничение: не все ChildVM реализуют все имеющиеся команды. Так как некоторые UserControl - по сути таблицы или списки, а некоторые представляют данные в виде "формы" с подробностями

Comment: Ну тогда попробуйте сделать как я написал

Comment: Скажите, а почему не работает вариант: AddNewItemCommand=ChildVM.AddNewItemCommand; ? Где первое - это команда в MainVM, а второе - команда в ChildVM

Comment: Что значит не работает? Где вы это написали?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79373/discussion-between---and--nop).